# Glade file widget

Tags: gtk3, glade

I want to create a glade file which should look like the gnome settings.
[image]

it would be great if someone could show me a example glade file or name me the widget that they use.

Comment: Do you want somebody to write your code too? \sarcasm

Comment: It looks like a [GtkListBox](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html#listbox) to me.

Comment: No thank you I want to do this by myself ;-) Thank you I only want to know which widget that is